# Refreshing my gridview to show updated records

Tags: asp.net, database, ms-access, gridview

To refresh the grid I thought the databind() should be called from what I'm reading.  I have my simple form collect name etc and its actually saving the information to the access database.  What I'm trying to do is is when I click save button for the information to save then update the grid with the new information.

Right now there is no error checking and its very simple.

Here is my code

```
        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\AddressBook.mdb");

        conn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string cmd = "SELECT * FROM tblAddressBook";

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, conn);

        da.Fill(ds, "Search");

        DataRow newRow = ds.Tables["Search"].NewRow();

        newRow[1] = txtFirstName.Text;
        newRow[2] = txtLastName.Text;
        newRow[3] = txtEmail.Text;
        newRow[4] = txtPhone.Text;

        ds.Tables["Search"].Rows.Add(newRow);

        OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
        cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables["Search"]);

        conn.Close();

        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Next to `conn.close();` you need to add DataSource to GridView like this:

```
conn.Close();
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Search"];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition. is the new error.  Removing one puts me right back in the same place where still cant see the grid update and have to check the db.

Comment: Can you post your markup for the gridview? Are you using any datasource in markup?

Comment: `<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AddressBook_ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AddressBook_ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblAddressBook]"></asp:SqlDataSource>`

Comment: In the datasource you are getting data from tblAddressBook, but in code you are updating "Search". I can't see how it supposed to work! Why don't you use UpdateCommand? You can check here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).